# Why can't I append to a <p> tag?

Tags: javascript

I am working on the scripting a ToDo list webapp, and I am trying to take the contents of 4 text boxes to create the content of the ToDo item.

Currently, when I try to connect the elements generated from the form, I get the error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementsByClassName.onclick`

I am currently using a function to create the element that I want to append to the body of the ToDo item, and I believe I am returning an element from my function. The code is posted below.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-accept-button')[0].onclick = function () {
    var formVals = {
        what: document.getElementById('todo-input-what').value,
        where: document.getElementById('todo-input-where').value,
        when: document.getElementById('todo-input-when').value,
        who: document.getElementById('todo-input-who').value,
        details: document.getElementById('todo-input-details').value
    };

    document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(function () {
        var fields = ["where", "when", "who", "details"];
        var root = document.createElement("SECTION").className = "todo";
        var title = document.createElement("H2").value = formVals.what;
        var body = document.createElement("DIV").className = "todo-body"

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var currentField = fields[i];
            var currentVal = formVals.currentField;

            body.appendChild(function () {
                var p = document.createElement("P").className = "indent-wrapped";
                var span = document.createElement("SPAN").class = currentField;
                var text = document.createTextNode(currentVal);
                span.value = currentField + ": ";
                p.appendChild(span);
                p.appendChild(text);

                return p;
            });
        }
        root.appendChild(title);
        root.appendChild(body);

        return root;
    });
    resetModal();
}
```

Comment: `root`, `title`, `span`, and `p` are not nodes, they're strings.

Comment: unless your body element has an id 'body' you need to reference it by calling  `document.body.appendChild(function () {...`; in either case you code is a total mess so no avail

Answer (score 1):

The variable `p` is not an item (HTML "Node"); it is a **string**.

That is, because you assigned it a string, using a sequence assignment (the last value goes all the way back) - `"indent-wrapped"` goes into `className` and then `className` goes into `p`.

Separate the item creation from the class assignment:

```
var p = document.createElement("P")
p.className = "indent-wrapped"
```

---

Same goes for `root`, `title` and `span`. They all are being assigned strings the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the string `indent-wrapped` to `p`, as you can see in the following snippet. So you try to call `appendChild` on a string instead of a node. Split the assignment, so you will first assign the node to p, and in the next statement set its classname. The same goes for the other elements (root, title, body, etc) where you try to create the element and set one of their properties in the same statement.

```js
var p = document.createElement("P").className = "indent-wrapped";
console.log(p);
```